# Trying to send email using smtp-relay.gmail.com and Nodemailer. Error ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: email, ssl, tls1.2, nodemailer, google-workspace

Trying to send email with G Suite `smtp-relay` using `Nodemailer`.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "username@mydomain.com",
    pass: "password"
  }
});

const result = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: `'"JOHN" <john@externaldomain.com>'`,
  to: "hello@mydomain.com",
  subject: "Hello",
  text: "Hello world!",
});
```

This is what G Suite says about using `TLS`: [Link1](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) [Link2](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100181?hl=en)

[image]

[image]

This is what Nodemailer says: [Link](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/)

[image]

**CONTINUE**

Basically G Suite tells me that I should use port 587 for TLS, and Nodemailer says I shouldn't.

Don't know if it has something to do with the ports, but this is the error I'm getting:

NOTE: I'm trying on port `587`.

> { [Error: 13252:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
>   ] code: 'ESOCKET', command: 'CONN' }

If I change to port `465`, I get this error:

> '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials ',
>     responseCode: 535,
>     command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }

I know my user and pass are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Basically G Suite tells me that I should use port 587 for TLS, and Nodemailer says I shouldn't.

Both talk about different things. The first one (G Suite) talks about SSL vs. TLS, i.e. compares various versions of the protocol. The second one (Nodemailer) talks about explicit vs. implicit TLS, i.e. explicitly upgrading a plain connection using the STARTTLS command (port 25 and 587) or establishing TLS directly after the TCP connect (port 465).

Thus, follow the recommendation from Nodemailer to set `secure: false`. If you want to enforce use of TLS, i.e. fail if STARTTLS is not supported by the mail server, then set `requireTLS: true` [as documented](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#tls-options).

Comment: That does work! Thank you for the detailed answer, Steffen.

Comment: I have done same thing and fixed same error but now getting another error `535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:`, I have cross checked my credential and logged in with same everything is good. I am using bigrock domain email service.

Comment: @TirathSharma: if you have a different question please ask it with full details (ideally reproducible by others) as a new question instead asking in a comment of an answer to a different question.